# Google Sheets - Cumulatively Add Values in Different Cells

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

How do you add up values in different cells?

I'm looking to create something similar to: https://i.etsystatic.com/7867478/r/il/09bb36/3897355233/il_1588xN.3897355233_koef.jpg

You will notice in the "expenses summary" box there are different descriptions such as food.

In the lower right corner, there are dropdown boxes for the category. There are multiple categories selected with varying amounts next to it.

Back to the "expenses summary" box there is a column named "actual" which adds up the values in the expenses tracker box.

In this case, this is $55 + $200 + $50 for food albeit in different boxes.

How does one add add these values up in a sheet where the category variable can be changed at anytime?

I have used vlookup to no avail. Fixing the cells would not work due to the variability of it.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of automatically modifying everything since it's notanother type of databases. The easiest way in my opinion is go to `Edit - Find and Replace` and `Replace All` those values. If the Data Validation is linked to a range, then it will be updated too